# process.traceDeprecation not working in webpack.config

Tags: webpack

There's a message that logged out in my command line when I compiled my JS files that says:

> (node:3276) DeprecationWarning: loaderUtils.parseQuery() received a
>   non-string value which oblematic, see
>   https://github.com/webpack/loader-utils/issues/56 parseQuery() will be
>   replaced with getOptions() in the next major version of loader-utils.

So I added the `process.traceDeprecation = true` as they advised, but it threw an error. How should I add it properly in my `webpack.config.js`?

Comment: starting process with `node --trace-deprecation` works for me

Answer (score 26):

`process.traceDeprecation = true;` is a statement that enables the deprecation stack traces in Node.js. It is a regular statement like assigning a regular variable. You probably added it to the configuration object which throws an error as it's not valid JavaScript. Simply put it as the first line in your `webpack.config.js`, so it looks like this:

```
process.traceDeprecation = true;

module.exports = {
  // Your config
};
```

If you're looking for a way to resolve the warning, you should have a look at [How to resolve the Webpack 2 loaderUtils.parseQuery() Warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42772413/how-to-resolve-the-webpack-2-loaderutils-parsequery-warning).

Comment: I'm doing exactly that, `process.traceDeprecation = true;` is the first line in currently used webpack config file, still no stacktrace shows up next to the warning. Actually I see output starting as: `(node:2180) DeprecationWarning: [....]`

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you're at the same directory as node_modules.

Run `node --trace-deprecation node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack`

Finally I found a way to set trace-deprecation to true.
It looks like simply set 
`process.traceDeprecation = true`
doesn't work for me. Maybe it's been overwritten somewhere else.