# Start NodeJS runtime in AWS lambda with a specific option or environment variable

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

Getting NodeJS deprecation error when execute an AWS Lambda (using node 12.x):

```
[DEP0066] DeprecationWarning: OutgoingMessage.prototype._headers is deprecated
```

can not find which module/piece of code is producing it. Nothing seems to reference [*_headers* or *_headerNames*](https://nodejs.org/api/deprecations.html#deprecations_dep0066_outgoingmessage_prototype_headers_outgoingmessage_prototype_headernames).

In Node should be possible to set a parameter or environment variable as [explain here](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_node_options_options) to `--trace-deprecation` and/or `--trace-warnings` and/or `--throw-deprecation`. When setting one or multiple of these values in AWS Console Environment variables for the lambda, no extra information is displayed.

[image: AWS lambda environment variables]

What is the way to set this runtime parameter for an AWS Lambda? Is there a way to catch the stack trace to know where is the deprecated error happening?

Comment: hard to say anything without looking at what code you have inside your lambda function

Comment: Hi @riga, looks that one of your dependencies are using the deprecated `_headers` ( https://nodejs.org/api/deprecations.html#deprecations_dep0066_outgoingmessage_prototype_headers_outgoingmessage_prototype_headernames ), can you post the code ?

Comment: @pepo i know this, my problem is to find which one.

Comment: Hi @riga, Oks. For enable the tracing you can use the `NODE_OPTIONS` env variable like this `NODE_OPTIONS='--trace-deprecation''` (https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_node_options_options)

Comment: @pepo I know this too,I am linking to this page in my question. What I want to know if is possible when executing the code inside AWS Lambda.

Comment: Hi @riga, I just made a quick test ( https://gist.github.com/pepoviola/aaba2d7af4d1b443b37e109f2702e358 ) setting that env variable and works as expected. Also, you can use `process.on('warning', warning =>  console.log( warning.stack ) );` to console.log the stack.

Comment: @pepo snipped helped me to set `traceDeprecation`. Can see the trace in the logs. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda :)

Comment: @Riga, setting the env var as you did worked for me (for another deprecation warning though). Are you sure the problem isn't somewhere else?

Comment: @FrancescRosas possibly, as far as I can remember could not get rid of the warning and  because time constraints we decided to live with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

feliz de ayudar! I pasted the snippet for the future.

set the flag in webpack.config.js code as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42922237/364568)

```
process.traceDeprecation = true;

module.exports = {
  // Your config
};
```

If the deprecation error is in a function you can do: (even **any** defeats purpose of Typescript, is just for locating the problem, to be removed after)

```
(process as any).traceDeprecation = true;
```

also can check the value

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    console.log( 'process.traceDeprecation', process.traceDeprecation );
    Buffer(1);
    process.on('warning', (warning) => {
        console.log( 'stack of deprecation' );
        console.log(warning.stack);
    });    
};
```

Thanks!